# Jython script for cluster

Tags: python, websphere, jython, websphere-8, jython-2.5

I need the Jython script to be run on WebSphere application server version 8 to

1. check if the application deployed on cluster scope is ready
2. Start a application deployed on cluster scope (other than AdminApplication.startApplicationOnCluster )
3. Stop a application deployed on cluster scope

Please help.

Comment: AdminApp has a method called 'isAppReady' that will check whether the application is ready to be run.  This could satisfy requirement 1.  Are there restrictions on AdminApp like there is with AdminApplication?

Comment: ok i will use isAppReady. could you please give suggestions for start and stop.

Answer (score 0):

`AdminApp.isReady` is used to check if an application is ready.

For starting and stopping its best to use `AdminApplication` from the scriptingLibraries, it is automatically imported to wsadmin (You can see its content in `/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/scriptLibraries/application/`)

`AdminApplication` contains the functions `startApplicationOnCluster` and `stopApplicationOnCluster` which is basically what you need.

Just give it an application name and a cluster name and it does the rest, for example:

```
# Start app
AdminApplication.startApplicationOnCluster("MyApp", "Mycluster01");

# Stop app
AdminApplication.stopApplicationOnCluster("MyApp", "Mycluster01");
```